# Bad Request Paypal

Tags: json, rest, paypal

Hello im developping a web application using JS,
so I'm developing a payments classes with Paypal REST API.
when I am sending the request to paypal Server .
I am getting  a message :

```
a bad Request 400
{
debug_id: "d32874630015c"
```

information_link: "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api

```
/#MALFORMED_REQUEST"
message: "Incoming JSON request does not map to API request"
name: "MALFORMED_REQUEST"
}
```

I am using Json expression here the `json` object :

```
"{
  "transactions":{
      "transactions":[],
      "amount": {
          "currency": "USD",
          "total": "7.47",
          "details": {
              "shipping":"",
              "subtotal":"",
              "tax":"",
              "fee":""
          }
      },
     "description": "This is the payment transaction description."
   },
  "links": [],
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer":{
      "fundingInstruments": {
          "creditCard": {
              "id":"",
              "number":"4417119669820331",
              "type":"visa",
              "expire_month":"11",
              "expire_year":"2018",
              "cvv2":"874", 
              "first_name":"Joe",
              "last_name":"Shopper",
              "billing_address": {
                  "line1":"52 N Main ST",
                  "line2":"",
                  "country_code":"US",
                  "postal_code":"43210",
                  "state":"OH",
                  "phone":"",
                  "city":"Johnstown"
              },
              "payer_id":"",
              "state":"",
              "valid_until":""
            },
            "creditCardToken": {
                "creditCardId":"",
                "payerId":"",
                "last4":"",
                "type":"",
                "expireMonth":"",
                "expireYear":""
            }
        },
        "paymentMethod":"credit_card"
    }
}"
```

Comment: What kind of request are you making to what url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of errors in your JSON.

```
{
   "transactions":[
      {
         "amount":{
            "currency":"USD",
            "total":"7.47"
         },
         "description":"This is the payment transaction description."
      }
   ],
   "intent":"sale",
   "payer":{
      "payment_method":"credit_card",
      "funding_instruments":[
         {
            "credit_card":{
               "number":"4417119669820331",
               "type":"visa",
               "expire_month":"11",
               "expire_year":"2018",
               "cvv2":"874",
               "first_name":"Joe",
               "last_name":"Shopper",
               "billing_address":{
                  "line1":"52 N Main ST",
                  "country_code":"US",
                  "postal_code":"43210",
                  "state":"OH",
                  "city":"Johnstown"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

You need to make sure you are keeping with the naming scheme from the Rest API Reference. Notice `fundingInstruments` (yours) vs `funding_instruments` (docs) and `creditCard` (yours) and `credit_card` (docs). Also `funding_instruments` is an array so you need to include `[]` around your list of instruments.

You have `transactions` listed twice, and you are including information you should not be including `payer_id`, `state`, `creditcardtoken` which does not exist. If you are setting a value to `""` it is best not to include it, because the server may check to see if it is formatted properly and give you this error.